# Defining element area/size to use a given number of pixels

Tags: css

I am looking for a CSS way to define element size using a number of pixels that element should use, as opposed to a specific width or length. Element must have area (therefore minimum width and height is 1).

Example 1. If requirement is to use 100 pixels, then an element whose parent container has width 10, should have height 10.

Example 2. If requirement is to use 155 pixels, then an element whose parent container has width 10, should have height 16.

I have a few ideas how this can be done, though all of them require JavaScript or statically coding the child nodes.

Comment: "*If requirement is to use 100 pixels, then an element whose parent container has width 25, should have height 25.*" - that's 25px² (625px), if it was to use 100px in total, it'd be 25px*4px, surely? And no, this isn't possible in CSS; you can specify the `witdh` and/or the `height`, you *can't* specify the `area`.

Comment: would be not possible without javascript to compute your desired area. There's css expressions but they are evil.

Comment: What prescribes the requirement? If that's known in front, then the height is simply a percentage of the width. Isn't it?